# Add multiple track locations via Git command line

Tags: git

Is there a vanilla Git command line that will look at a file in my repository and start tracking each path under that.

Like `git5 track --list=//depot/a/b/c/track_paths`?

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in `track_paths`; do git track line; done
```

Comment: will that pull it from a file in the repository?  I'm looking for a simple one-shot solution

Answer (score 0):

There is no `git track` command. A better name for the file would be "track-branches". Script-wise, you can use `cat` instead of read:

```
cat track-branches | xargs -n 1 -i{} git branch --track {} origin/{}
```

This depends if you have track_paths as a file that exists on the currently checked out commit. This also assumes you have no local branches of that name yet. You can force local branches to be overwritten with the `--force` option on the branch command.